# Filter array of objects by another array with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have this array of objects:

```
const data = [
    {
       id: 1,
       name: 'Name1',
       encryptionKey: 'AAA'
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       name: 'Name2',
       encryptionKey: 'BBB'
    },
    {
       id: 3,
       name: 'Name3',
       encryptionKey: 'CCC'
    }
 ]
```

and another array of encryption keys:

```
const encryptionKeys = ['AAA', 'BBB']
```

I am then filtering the `data` array based on the `encryptionKeys` array like this:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(item) {
   return encryptionKeys.indexOf(item.encryptionKey) !== -1;
});
```

which **works** and filters the objects and saves them in a new array. The **problem** is however if the `encryptionKey` array has duplicated keys, for example:

```
const encryptionKeys = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB']
```

then all duplicate keys will be ignored and the filtered array will only have, in this case, 2 objects instead of 3. What am I doing wrong in my filtering code? The filtered array should have duplicate objects if the `encryptionKeys` array has duplicate values.

Comment: do you have items in `encryptionKeys` which are not in `data`?

Comment: What output do you expect with duplicated keys

Comment: So if `BBB` exists `n` times then you want the Objects with the encryptionKey `BBB` to appear in the filtered result `n` times?

Comment: Exactly @FrancisLeigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make note of [.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) 's Browser compatibility and then see [@babel/polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill)

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name1',
    encryptionKey: 'AAA'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name2',
    encryptionKey: 'BBB'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Name3',
    encryptionKey: 'CCC'
  }
]
const keys = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'ZZZ']

const occurances = data.map(d => {
  const { encryptionKey } = d
  const keyedOccurances = keys
                        .filter(k => k === encryptionKey)
                        .map(k => encryptionKey === k && d)

  return keyedOccurances.length && keyedOccurances
})
.filter(Boolean)
.flat()

console.log(occurances)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy - just use `filter` on `encryptionKeys` beforehand:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(item) {
   return encryptionKeys.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) == i).indexOf(item.encryptionKey) !== -1;
});
```

Alternatively, make an `Array` from a `Set`:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(item) {
   return [...new Set(encryptionKeys)].indexOf(item.encryptionKey) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: I tried your solutions but the filtered array still has only 2 objects instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Make your encryption keys unique before you compare and filter it.

```js
var encryptionKeys = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB'];
var unique = encryptionKeys.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); 
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted items.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Name1', encryptionKey: 'AAA' }, { id: 2, name: 'Name2', encryptionKey: 'BBB' }, { id: 3, name: 'Name3', encryptionKey: 'CCC' }],
    encryptionKeys = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB'],
    result = encryptionKeys.map(key => data.find(o => o.encryptionKey === key));
     
console.log(result);
```

A short approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and filtering the keys in advance.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Name1', encryptionKey: 'AAA' }, { id: 2, name: 'Name2', encryptionKey: 'BBB' }, { id: 3, name: 'Name3', encryptionKey: 'CCC' }],
    encryptionKeys = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'DDD'],
    map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.encryptionKey, o])),
    result = encryptionKeys
        .filter(Map.prototype.has, map)
        .map(Map.prototype.get, map);
     
console.log(result);
```